# Symfony2: property value not received for custom field type

Tags: forms, symfony, types, field

in my form I need to create my own field type called 'ImageType' in order to display an  tag.

Here the code I use to create the form:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($image)
            ->add('title')
            ->add('description')
            ->add('file')
            ->add('path', new ImageFieldType());
```

Here the ImageTypeField definition:

```
class ImageFieldType extends AbstractType
{
    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
    {
        return array(
            'path' => null,
        );
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'field';
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'imageField';
    }
}
```

And the template:

```
{% block imageField_widget %}
    {% if path is not null %}
        <img src="{{ asset('upload/dir/' ~ path) }}" />
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

My problem is that `path` is always null.
I was expecting to receive the value of `path` property of `$image` when using the `createFormBuilder()->add('path'`....

Can somebody help me please?

**UPDATE:**
Solved, I was using `form.vars.value.path`, but `form.vars.value` was enough!

Answer (score 0):

If `path` comes from your form, then you will retrieve it in your form:

```
form.vars.value.path
```

Example:

```
{% if form.vars.value.path is not null %}
    <img src="{{ asset('upload/dir/' ~ form.vars.value.path) }}" />
{% endif %}
```

Comment: It doesn't work, it says: Item "path" for "" does not exist in MyBundle:City:manage.html.twig at line 9. At that line there is `{{ form_widget(form) }}`

Comment: Maybe it's just "form" afterall. See [how to customize an individual field](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#how-to-customize-an-individual-field).

Comment: There is something missing.... the link you provide describes how to customize a theme for a field type already existing, I can't use that code for my field type definition